# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Tags: reactjs

i am facing this problem right now on my react web-app. I try to map the students data from the laravel API that i created. Suddenly the web-app show this error to me `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')`

Below is my code

```
state = {
        students: [],
        loading: true,
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/students');

       /*  console.log(res); */

        if(res.data.status === 200){
            this.setState({
                students: res.data.students,
                loading: false,
            });
        }
    }

    render(){

        var student_HTMLTABLE = "";
        if(this.state.loading){
            
            student_HTMLTABLE = 
            <tr>
                <td colSpan="7">
                    <h2>Loaidng ...</h2>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
        else{

            student_HTMLTABLE = 
            this.state.students.map( (item) => {

                return(
                <tr key={item.id}>
                    <td>{item.id}</td>
                    <td>{item.name}</td>
                    <td>{item.course}</td>
                    <td>{item.email}</td>
                    <td>{item.phone}</td>
                    <td><Link to={`/edit-students/${item.id}`} className="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Edit</Link></td>
                    <td><Link to={`/delete-students/${item.id}`} className="btn btn-danger">Delete</Link></td>
                </tr>
                );
                });
            
        }
```

Please help me on how to solve this problem, almost 1 hour googling and still stuck :(

Comment: `res.data.students` is likely undefined when you update the state.  Did you verify that it contains the data you expect?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just change it to `students: res.data.students ?? [],`
This will fix your problem in case students or data is empty.

Comment: This doesn't necessarily help the OP.  Likely the API request was returning different data than what was expected thus the `undefined` array.

Comment: I was thinking maybe in some cases, the server was returning empty data with status 200 or no students key in data object :).

Answer (score 0):

> This error is because your value is null and you're not checking null.
> Try this code

```
 // null check
 {
   this.state.students && this.state.students.map((student , idx)=>{
     // do some thing
   })
 }
```